# defaultdict(list) python with complex number keys to

Tags: python, list, numpy, complex-numbers, defaultdict

I am trying to use Python `defaultdict(list)` with complex numbers keys.
The result is that different values with the same keys are inserted to different lists, instead of to the same list. How can this be solved?

```
comp_arr = np.array([5+6j, 7+8j, 5+6j, 7+8j, 8+3j])
comp_dict= defaultdict(list)

for i in comp_arr.shape:
    (comp_dict[comp_arr [i]]).append(i)
```

Comment: Your `defaultdict` looks fine. Your `for i in comp_arr.shape` doesn't do what you think it does. Try `for i in range(len(comp_arr)):`

Comment: Be careful about using complex and/or float values as keys.  The inexactness of floats could mean that apparently equal values will be filed as different keys.  In this simple case this doesn't seem to be a problem, but watch out in more realistic cases.

Comment: @hpaulj indeed, this was my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looping on the wrong thing, try using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for the loop:

#### Code:

```
for i, x in enumerate(comp_arr):
    comp_dict[x].append(i)
```

#### Test Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

comp_arr = np.array([5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 5 + 6j, 7 + 8j, 8 + 3j])
comp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i, x in enumerate(comp_arr):
    comp_dict[x].append(i)

print(comp_dict)
```

#### Results:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {(5+6j): [0, 2], (7+8j): [1, 3], (8+3j): [4]})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the action of looping with both i, and x?

Comment: @AL_P, This is not looping on `i` and `x`.  It is looping on the contents of `comp_arr`.  `i` is the index of `x` in `comp_arr`.  Check the docs for `enumerate`, which I linked to.